# How to select multiple options for a var - jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that I am currently using that allows me to show/hide certain elements while using ajax. It does work, however there is a single issue which is I cannot set it to work with multiple values in the statement.

I have tried splitting these in different ways such as:

'/page1', '/page2'

'/page1' || '/page2'

As examples, could anyone assist with the correct way to split multiple values.

This is the script I am trying to get this to work in:

```
window.addEventListener("mercury:load", function(){ 

$(function(){

var currPath = window.location.pathname;

  $('.path').text('Current path is : '+ currPath);
    if(currPath == '/about-us'){
      $('.LogoContainerLight').hide();
      $('.NavButtons').addClass("NavButtonsActive");
    }else {
      $('.LogoContainerLight').show();
      $('.NavButtons').removeClass("NavButtonsActive");
    }

  })
});
```

I am a novice in this area, so I might be asking for something rather simple - I have also tried searching.

what I want to achieve:

```
if(currPath == '/about-us', '/services', '/page-url'){
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `if ( currPath ===  '/about-us' || currPath === '/services') { ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, but I think the most elegant is:

```js
if (['/about-us', '/services', '/page-url'].includes(currPath)) {
  ...
}
```

It is less code than just going through each path and checking whether it == currPath, and it is easier to add items to without creating unnecessarily long if statements. A more oldschool approach is:

```js
if (['/about-us', '/services', '/page-url'].indexOf(currPath) !== -1) {
  ...
}
```